# Swift: Parsing JSON, NSDictionary of NSDictionaries

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary

I am trying to parse a `JSON` file with some tags and sub tags. I am doing this by creating a `NSDictionary`. From this I create a `NSDictionary` from a certain tag. This `NSDictionary` contains the properties I want to parse. So I am trying to loop over the `NSDictionary`, but it is not working. I tried many variants of this, but it keeps giving me compile time errors.

```
var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

var devices:NSDictionary = jsonResult.objectForKey("devices") as NSDictionary

for device:NSDictionary in devices{

    device.objectForKey("id")
    //etc
    //etc
}
```

I get the following error:

```
'(key: AnyObject, value: AnyObject)' is not convertible to 'NSDictionary'
```

on the for each loop line. I've also tried casting it to NSDictionary after, but then I get the same error.

For clarification, this is an example of what my json file looks like:

```
{  
   "global":{  
      //etc
   },
   "user":{  
    //etc
   },
   "devices":[  
      {  
         "id":16108,
         //etc
      },
      {
          “id”:12310,
          //etc
      },
        //etc
},
```

etc obviously means theres more data, this is just a basic outline. I am trying to read the properties of the devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `objectForKey("devices")` returns an `NSArray` and not a `NSDictionary`

Comment: It did work in Objective-C, is there any way I can return a NSDictionary instead of an NSArray?

Comment: Based on the JSON example you provided, there is no way that this returns a NSDictionary.

Comment: Then how do I actually read the individual properties? The items in the Array can't be cast to Arrays.

Comment: The NSArray (devices) holds objects of type NSDictionary

Answer (score -1):

Works for me:

```
        var error: NSError?
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary

        var devices = jsonResult.objectForKey("devices") as NSArray?
        if devices != nil {
            for device in devices! {
                var deviceId = device.objectForKey("id") as NSNumber
                println("deviceId: \(deviceId)")
            }
        }
```